# How to link URL images extracted from Google Drive in ckeditor5

Tags: ckeditor

I extracted the Google Drive image address with a URL extraction program.

I want to import the url address from CKEditor 5.
not the local image upload.

I want to see the image in the textarea.

How could I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far to get it working? What have you found in your research?

Comment: I think there is a way.
Look for options or plugins.

Comment: @DR.SA: Any luck of using Google Drive images on textarea of CK Editor ? if yes then could you please share the solution? Appreciate :)